# How to run the 46 line blog tutorial of Apache Sling?

Tags: osgi, sling

I'm trying to go through [this tutorial](http://sling.apache.org/site/46-line-blog.html) of Apache Sling and I'm stuck at the beginning. I can't display the blog form in my browser. Instead, I get the following message:

```
Resource dumped by HtmlRendererServlet

Resource path: /content/blog/*

Resource metadata: {sling.resolutionPathInfo=.html, sling.resolutionPath=/content/blog/*}

Resource type: sling:syntheticStarResource

Resource super type: -
Resource Value:
```

I saw on [the README](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/samples/espblog/README.txt) that this might be caused by `org.apache.sling.samples.path-based.rtp` not running. However I made sure the bundle was active in the Felix console. (I tried to install from the OSGi repository tab of the console, then by downloading the jar and dropping it under sling/startup/15 but it didn't change anything)

I'm wondering if there are extra configuration steps I should take?

Please note that I'm new to OSGi and Sling so this is probably a beginner's mistake.

Edit: I noticed in the Felix console in the component tab that `org.apache.sling.samples.pathbasedrtp.DefaultResourceTypeProvider` had the status "unsatisfied". Could it be related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was indeed a problem (visible by clicking the bundle name at `/system/console/bundles`) that prevented the `o.a.s.samples.path-based.rtp` bundle from starting with recent versions of Sling.

I have just fixed it ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-2557 ), please try again!